# Dialogflow Webhook Fulfillment not showing in Google Assistant Simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to use Fulfillment with a Webhook to return a JSON to Dialogflow that will show a card in Google Assistant. I got the JSON directly from here:
https://developers.google.com/actions/conversation-api-playground

However, the card is not showing in the Google Assistant Simulator. 
The simulator has a tab called "Response" and I can see the json response.
No errors in the error tab.

[image: Google Assistant Simulator]

[image: Dialogflow Intent]

Comment: Can you update the question to include a screen shot of what you *do* see in the simulator when you try this?

Comment: In the first screenshot the simulator is showing the text “test simple” that is got from the dialogflow intent response. The first screenshot also shows the webhook json response that it received. The simulator is not showing the image card or the simple response

Comment: Can you try unchecking the "Use responses from default tab as first response"? It could be using the response set in the dialogflow responses instead of the Google ones right now

Comment: Ok I just tried that, same result

Comment: I'm specifically asking for what is showing on the "Display" tab.

Comment: Oh sorry, here's an image showing the display. https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7eggty7yh29len/DF-Display.png?dl=0

It only shows "test simple"  because that is what I have in the intent response

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a subTitle to the basic card? That might be the issue here.

```html
conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    text: 'This is the Text',
    title: 'Title',
    subtitle: "This is a subtitle",
    buttons: new Button({
      title: 'Read More',
      url: 'https://assistant.google.com/',
    }),
    image: new Image({
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
      alt: 'Image alternate text',
    }),
}));
```

Please make these changes and try again.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using the inline editor, I'm using the webhook json response. And I got the response directly from here: https://developers.google.com/actions/conversation-api-playground

Comment: I was facing the same issue last night. But adding the subtitle fixed it. Have you atleast tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have. Here's an image of the response that has a subtitle in it. The display tab still only shows "test simple".
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0maj8mu2na9cz92/DF_with_subtitle.png?dl=0

Comment: I see, Can you provide a snapshot of your webhook code? Let me see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: All I do is return the code that I got from here: https://developers.google.com/actions/conversation-api-playground